# angularjs timestamp to datetime format string in input field

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, datetime, timestamp

I am saving datetime in timestamp string using the following:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); 
$bdatetime = "31-03-2016 21:52";
            $date = new DateTime($bdatetime);
            $bdatetimeTS = $date->getTimestamp();
```

which is saving fine. And I can fetch that timestamp and convert it back to its original format using following in angular js:

```
<td>{{item.bdatetime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yy'}}</td>
```

which is displaying fine all the list of records.

Now I need to edit individual records, in edit form, I have the following field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="bdatetime" value="{{bdatetime * 1000 | date:'dd-MM-yy'}}" name="bdatetime" id="datetimepicker" required/>
```

in JS and binding it using the following:

```
$scope.bdatetime = data[0].bdatetime;
```

which is showing timestamp in input field rather then showing time date in format in the specific format.

I know how to convert timestamp to datetime format for [non-bindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date).

How can I do this for bindable input field?

[This is from string to time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677970/angularjs-get-timestamp-from-a-human-readable-date) but I kind of need a reverse solution from timestamp to input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timestamp = data[0].bdatetime;
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
var datevalues = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
$scope.bdatetime = datevalues;
```

Comment: Is there no way to do something like this: {{new Date(x.Name.ActualSendTimeStamp * 1000) | date:'dd-MM-yy }}

Answer (score 0):

ng-model and value can't be used together. You should use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date or write custom directive that handles ngModel controller.

Comment: I am already using http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ plugin, which I find better.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549933/jquery-datetime-picker-plugin-does-not-work-with-angularjs-in-ng-view/21607980#21607980